# use kafka to start Kylin Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, kylin

When I use kafka to start Kylin Stream,I got the following exception as picture,hope someone can help me ,thanks very much:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbo3Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

checked the image .It seems to be the WARN not Exception.Check the input and try with the stable version of Kylin